# Is there any methods to remove these quotes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

**I have a collection of data like this -**

```
[
 0: {latitude: "0", longitude: "0", user_country_name: "-", user_country_code: "-", total_visitors: 4}
 1: {latitude: "-33.867851", longitude: "151.207321", user_country_name: "Australia", user_country_code: "AU", total_visitors: 1}
 2: {latitude: "-23.960831", longitude: "-46.333611", user_country_name: "Brazil", user_country_code: "BR", total_visitors: 1}
 3: {latitude: "45.411171", longitude: "-113.468712", user_country_name: "Canada", user_country_code: "CA", total_visitors: 2}
 4: {latitude: "47.366669", longitude: "8.55", user_country_name: "Switzerland", user_country_code: "CH", total_visitors: 1}
]
```

**I get the result by using**

```
var location_data = [];
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data, 
    success: function(data)
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        obj.forEach(function(item) {
          var data = { latLng: '['+parseFloat(item.latitude)+', '+parseFloat(item.longitude)+']', name: item.user_country_name }

          location_data.push(data);

        })
    } 
  });
```

**Output  :**

```
[
 0: {latLng: "[0, 0]", name: "-"}
 1: {latLng: "[-33.867851, 151.207321]", name: "Australia"}
 2: {latLng: "[-23.960831, -46.333611]", name: "Brazil"}
 3: {latLng: "[45.411171, -113.468712]", name: "Canada"}
 4: {latLng: "[47.366669, 8.55]", name: "Switzerland"}
]
```

But I want something like the following, I mean display the item of the object like [-33.867851, 151.207321] not wrapped with **""quotes**;

**Expected Output:**

```
[
     0: {latLng: [0,0], name: "-"}
     1: {latLng: [-33.867851, 151.207321], name: "Australia"}
     2: {latLng: [-23.960831, -46.333611], name: "Brazil"}
     3: {latLng: [45.411171, -113.468712], name: "Canada"}
     4: {latLng: [47.366669, 8.55], name: "Switzerland"}
]
```

Comment: `latLng: '['+parseFloat(item.latitude)+', '+parseFloat(item.longitude)+']'` Don't _generate it as string_ in the first place. `latLng: [parseFloat(item.latitude), parseFloat(item.longitude)]`

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Nick None of these answers solved my problem. And I have to fix it from the PHP end.

Comment: You cannot fix this from the PHP end as that is not where the problem is. The problem is in your JS code, which is what the answers show you how to fix.

Comment: @Nick, since I couldn't figure out what is the actual problem in js and how to fix it, I posted it here and asked for a solution. But since I didn't get a solution here I have to focus on my PHP code and passed a custom array to lat long field.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse each item's `latitude`, `longitute` properties to numbers and add them as the 2 elements of a `latLng` array.

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the most appropriate way to iterate and transform.

```js
const arr = [
  { latitude: "-33.23", longitude: "44.22", user_country_name: "Italy", user_country_code: "-", total_visitors: 4},
  { latitude: "-15.25", longitude: "66.55", user_country_name: "Spain", user_country_code: "-", total_visitors: 4}
]

const output = arr.map(item => {
  return {
    name: item.user_country_name,
    latLng: [+item.latitude, +item.longitude]
  }
})

console.log(output)
```